# JDBC driver not found (servlet, DAO, mariaDB)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, mariadb

I have an exercise which requires to create:

1. a JSP - to display the data forwarded by the servlet
2. a servlet - to get data from the DAO class and forward to JSP
3. a DAO class - to connect and retrieve data from mariaDB database

The **problem** is I cannot open the connection to the database in the servlet. When I debug servlet file, it broke at the line creating new DAO object (I marked the line within **...** below), in the DAO file, it cannot open the connection with the message "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a1605354"; even though I did add jdbc driver for mariaDB in the build path.

I included the picture of my project explorer at the end of the post. I am so confused and do not understand the problem clearly to fix it. Really need your help!

I have a file named "Connection Parameters" with all the information needed to connect to mariaDB:

**ConnectionParameter.java**

```
public class ConnectionParameters {

public static final String username = "a1605354"; 
public static final String password = "jaZEMs85o";


private static final String databaseName = username;
public static final String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databaseName;
public static final String jdbcDriver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";

// PK violation: error code in MariaDB is 1062
public static final int PK_VIOLATION_ERROR = 1062;
}
```

**StudentDAO.java**

```
public class StudentDAO {
private final String username;
private final String password;
private final String databaseURL;

public StudentDAO() throws Exception {
    username = ConnectionParameters.username;
    password = ConnectionParameters.password;
    databaseURL = ConnectionParameters.databaseURL;

    try {
        Class.forName(ConnectionParameters.jdbcDriver);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Connection openConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, username, password);
    return dbConnection;
}

private void closeConnection(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException {
    if (dbConnection != null) {
        dbConnection.close();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {
        dbConnection = openConnection();
        String sqlText = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, streetaddress, postcode, postoffice FROM Student ORDER BY lastname";

        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlText);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String firstname = resultSet.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = resultSet.getString("lastname");
            String streetaddress = resultSet.getString("streetaddress");
            String postcode = resultSet.getString("postcode");
            String postoffice = resultSet.getString("postoffice");

            studentList.add(new Student(id, firstname, lastname, streetaddress, postcode, postoffice));
        }

        return studentList;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    } finally {
        closeConnection(dbConnection);
    }
}
```

**StudentListServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet("/StudentListServlet")
public class StudentListServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        **StudentDAO studentDAO = new StudentDAO();**
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = studentDAO.getAllStudents();


        request.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("StudentList.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

  }

}
```

**StudentList.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
```

```
<body>
    <h2>List of Students</h2>
    <br/>
    <form action="StudentListServlet" method="GET"></form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Street</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Post Office</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${ studentList }" var="studentListObject">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.id }" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.lastname }" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.firstname }" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.streetaddress }" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.postcode }" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${studentListObject.postoffice }" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Project explorer view:

[image]

Comment: *even though I did add jdbc driver for mariaDB in the build path* are you sure of this? Do you have the jdbc driver for Maria DB inside WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Based on your image, you don't even have a lib folder inside WEB-INF.